# Does php wait for a response from an API call?

Tags: php

How is the best way to call an external domain from within a php script. Is it curl ? And if so does php wait for the line to be processed before moving on so that we can be sure of the return data.

Comment: not sure why this is downvoted, it's a pretty clear question

Answer (score 4):

The easeiest way to get a response from an external URL is to use file_get_contents(), but cURL is definitely the better way if you want to have more options or send post data. Both of these functions wait for the response, though. PHP is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Actually, there're few workarounds to make asynchronous requests and also experimental library [pthreads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php).

Comment: Thanks so this will hang if the API is unresponsive ! Will check the other answer now.

Comment: if you're using curl, then you'd wanna set the curl timeout option to prevent excessive hanging. e.g. `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); //allow 5 secs`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Curl, file_get_contents (with the appropriate extensions loaded) or do some socket work.

```
class Tools
{
public static function post_request($url, $datos) 
{
    $resultado=null;
    $datos=http_build_query($datos);
    $url=parse_url($url);

    // extract host and path:
    $host=$url['host'];
    $ruta=$url['path'];

    $socket=fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if($socket)
    {
        // send the request headers:
        fputs($socket, "POST $ruta HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Host: $host\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Content-length: ". strlen($datos) ."\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
        fputs($socket, $datos);

        while(!feof($socket))
        {
            $resultado.= fgets($socket, 128);
        }
    }
    else die('ERROR');

    fclose($socket);

    $resultado=explode("\r\n\r\n", $resultado, 2);
    $header=isset($resultado[0]) ? $resultado[0] : '';
    $contenido=isset($resultado[1]) ? $resultado[1] : '';

    return array(
        'status' => 'ok',
        'header' => $header,
        'content' => $contenido
        );
    }
};
```

If I remember correctly, the script won't proceed until the request is processed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Use cURL and yes it will wait for a reply (or failure).

Comment: So it does return and allow the script to continue to stop a hanging scenario. I wonder how much control we have over that. Ie is it returning a failure after no response from server after 1 second for example.

Comment: See the cURL option CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: There are a lot of options with curl and I have also seen this example here which uses curl in a client php script http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/creating-an-api-centric-web-application/ So this gives me even more confidence to use it. TY